# `dask-kubernetes` scheduler - worker on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dask, dask.distributed, dask-kubernetes

I've been trying to set up a `dask.distributed` cluster using `kubernetes`. Setting up the `kube` cluster itself is pretty straightforward, the problem I am currently struggling with is that I can't get the local scheduler to connect to the workers. Workers can connect to the scheduler, but they advertise an address inside the `kube` network that is not accessible to the scheduler running outside the `kube` network.

Following the examples from the `dask-kubernetes` docs I got a `kube` cluster running on AWS and (on a separate AWS machine) started a `notebook` with the local `dask.distributed` scheduler. The scheduler launches a number of workers on the `kube` cluster, but it can not connect to said workers because the workers are on a different network: the internal `kube` network.

The network setup looks like the following:

- notebook server running on 192.168.0.0/24
- `kube` cluster EC2 instances also on 192.168.0.0/24
- `kube` pods on 100.64.0.0/16

the `dask` scheduler runs on `192.168.0.0/24` but the `dask` workers are on `100.64.0.0/16` - how do I connect the two? Should I be running the scheduler also in a `kube` pod, edit routing tables, try to figure out the host machines' IPs address on the workers?

The workers are able to connect to the scheduler, but in the scheduler I get a errors of the form

> distributed.scheduler - ERROR - Failed to connect to worker 'tcp://100.96.2.4:40992': Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://100.96.2.4:40992' after 3.0 s: connect() didn't finish in time

I'm not looking for a list of possible things I *could* do, I'm looking for the *recommended* way of setting this up, specifically in relation to `dask.distributed`.

I set up the `kube` cluster using `kops`.

https://dask-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I've typically used dask-kubernetes from within the Kubernetes cluster, though obviously this isn't ideal for everyone.

Networks can vary.  My guess is that the IP address chosen by default is not visible to your Kubernetes network.  If you do have an address to which your workers can connect you can specify it in the `ip=` keyword argument.

```
cluster = KubeCluster(ip='scheduler-address-visible-to-workers')
```

If there is a network interface that you know to be visible then you can generalize this as follows:

```
from distributed.utils import get_ip_interface
ip = get_ip_interface('eth0')  # replace eth0 with your visible network interface
```

On UNIX based systems you can usually find a list of suitable interfaces with the `ifconfig` command.  You might look through that list for an address that is similar to the addresses that you're seeing on the workers.

If neither of these is possible then I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask-kubernetes/issues/new

Comment: There's no problem with the workers connecting to the scheduler, which is what `cluster = KubeCluster(ip='scheduler-address-visible-to-workers')` seems to solve. The scheduler can't connect to the worker, because the workers advertise an address inside the `kube` network `100.64.0.0/16`. So I guess the solution is to run `KubeCluster` also inside the `kube` network?

Comment: Running within the Kube network would certainly work.  If you think it's important to support cases where the user is launching KubeCluster outside of the cluster then I recommend raising an issue.